# Create msi using powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, azure-devops, biztalk, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've got BizTalk application built(CI) in VSTS. My deployment needs to create .msi file from built Artifacts. I believe, it could be done through PowerShell script task in release pipeline.

Could someone help me with PowerShell script to create msi.

Comment: why down vote? could the person explain......

Comment: Why bother with painful windows installer technology? There's nothing you can do with it that you cant do even easier with a powershell script. If you have to do an MSI, the WixTooolset would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell does not have a built-in MSI creator, but you can use an official Microsoft extension to Visual Studio to do that, it is called Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects.

Here is the link to Visual Studio 2015 extension: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

And if you are using 2017: [Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

You can then create a Setup Project in your solution.

You can find the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I've installed [Microsoft VS2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects). I find no next step. Please help

Comment: New -> Project -> In Installed Templates, search for Setup Project and create a new one.

Comment: Use this documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the BizTalk Deployment Framework in you Solution?

That is generally the best way to generate installers for BizTalk based Solutions.  Since BTDF itself uses msbuild, automating it is not a issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check BizTalkFactory PowerShell Provider? This adds PowerShell commands to manage BizTalk and there is one to export an application as MSI:

```
Export-Application -Path MyBizTalkApp -Package Z:\MyPackage.msi
```